# Solution for the differential equation $(1-x^2y)dx + (x^2y-x^3)dy = 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the next differential equation $(1-x^2y)dx + (x^2y-x^3)dy = 0$

Now I know that this is a classic example for the integrating factor method, and this problem is given as an example in a lot of places for this method, but the problem I encounter is that after finding the function $h(x)=\frac{1}{x^2}$ and dividing the $1$-form from above by $h(x)$ gets me with $(\frac{1}{x^2}-y)dx+(y-x)dy=0$

which is a closed $1$-form. 
Now is when the problem occurs, because the usual way of approaching this is by applying Poincare's lemma, and the $1$-form above being exact. But I don't think we can apply Poincare's lemma because $\frac{1}{x^2} - y $ is defined over $R^2$ without the $Oy$ axis (where $x=0$), which is not an open ball. Am I missing something?

Comment: I don't know about a formal proof, but informally you can say that a trajectory of this equation will be in one half plane or the other, and a half plane is contractible. This is different from a situation where you have a closed form with a singularity that can be "looped around" which can "really" cause the form to be non-exact, such as the classic $-y/(x^2+y^2) dx + x/(x^2+y^2) dy$.

Comment: I understand what you are saying but considering that I have a closed form defined over $R^2$ without the $0,0$ point, can't I say, by the same logic, that we can apply Poincare over the first, second, third or fourth quadrant?

Comment: No, because now you can actually draw a loop entirely inside the domain around the hole that you can't contract. That is the catch. The plane without an axis is not contractile but its connected components are contractible.

Comment: well, ok, but considering the equation you wrote before: $-y/(x^2+y^2) dx + x/(x^2+y^2) dy = 0$ what would you do about this? just multiply by $(x^2+y^2)$ and get $yy'=x$?

Comment: To handle that case, you must impose some additional domain restriction to make sense of a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiply by the Ansatz $x^ay^b$ to obtain a condition of the form $df=f_xdx=f_ydy=0$ so$$\begin{align}f_x&=x^ay^b-x^{a+2}y^{b+1},\\f_y&=x^{a+2}y^{b+1}-x^{a+3}y^b\\\implies0&=\frac{(f_x)_y-(f_y)_x}{x^ay^{b-1}}\\&=b-(b+1)x^3y-(a+2)xy^2+(a+3)x^2y\\\implies(a,\,b)&=(-2,\,0).\end{align}$$So$$df=\left(\frac{1}{x^2}-y\right)dx+\left(y-x\right)dy\implies f=-\frac1x-xy+\frac12y^2+C.$$Since $df=0$, we can impose $f=0$, viz.$$\frac1x+xy-\frac12y^2=C.$$

Answer (score 2):

$$(1-x^2y)dx+(x^2y-x^3)dy==0 \implies (\frac{1}{x^2}-y)dx+(y-x)dy=0$$
This is exact ODE. So the solution is $$\int (\frac{1}{x^2}-y) dx+\int y dy=C \implies -1/x-yx+y^2/2=C$$